# Are Vegito and Gogeta canon?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

http://fictionalomniverse.forumotion.com/t845-vegito-vs-gogeta

This post basically stated
Vegito is 100% Canon and that Gogeta is semi-canon?

Comment: Welcome! you might want to include the piece you are referring to in your actual post, instead of only linking (keeping the link as resource is okay). And your question could use some re-phrasing, if you want us to confirm what the post says (yes/no) then this would not be a really good question. If you want us to answer which of the 2 is cannon, it would be ;)

Comment: I think "semi-canon" is a perfect way to describe Gogeta. The method of fusion used to create Gogeta is canon (as seen with Gotenks), so we know he COULD exist canonically.

Answer (score 4):

Vegito is canon because he exists in the Manga (main canon of Dragon Ball). Gogeta doesn't exist in the Manga and only exists in the Anime and Movies which are considered alternate versions of Dragon Ball from the Manga therefore not canon.

Answer (score -1):

Gogeta may not be canon but he can technically. The fusion dance is canon since goten and trunks do it in the majin buu saga and even in dragon ball super. That dance (obviously) fused goten and trunks into gotenks